# Adding vectors of doubles of differing sizes in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a number of vector containers of varying size each containing doubles. 
I would like to add the elements of each vector to create a single vector 
of doubles. This simple example will example what I'm talking about:

Consider two vectors A with three elements 3.0 2.0 1.0 and B with two elements 
2.0 1.0. I would like to add both vectors starting at the last element and working 
backwards. This would give an array C with entries 3.0 4.0 2.0.

What would be the most elegant/efficent way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: there's a nifty feature in some languages called iteration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you know you have one vector that is larger than the other

```
std::vector<double> new_vector = bigger_vector; // Copy the largest
std::transform(smaller_vector.rbegin(), smaller_vector.rend(), // iterate over the complete smaller vector 
    bigger_vector.rbegin(), // 2nd input is the corresponding entries of the larger vector  
    new_vector.rbegin(),    // Output is the new vector 
    std::plus<double>());   // Add em
```

This is nice because you don't have to do any loop indentation, and works on any sequence container that supports reverse iterators.

Answer (score 4):

Try this with iterators:

```
#include <vector>

void add(
        std::vector<double>& result,
        const std::vector<double>& a,
        const std::vector<double>& b)
{
    std::vector<double>::const_reverse_iterator sit;
    std::vector<double>::const_reverse_iterator send;

    // copy the larger vector
    if (a.size() > b.size() ) {
        result = a;
        sit  = b.rbegin();
        send = b.rend();
    }
    else {
        result = b;
        sit  = a.rbegin();
        send = a.rend();
    }

    // add the smaller one, starting from the back
    for (std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator it = result.rbegin();
            sit != send;
            ++it, ++sit)
    {
        *it += *sit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy the larger vector into C and then add (+=) the elements of the smaller against the associated elements of C.

Somthing like:

```
std::vector<double> add(const std::vector<double>& a,
                        const std::vector<double>& b)
{
    std::vector<double> c( (a.size() > b.size()) ? a : b );
    const std::vector<double>& aux = (a.size() > b.size() ? b : a);
    size_t diff = c.size() - aux.size();

    for (size_t i = diff; i < c.size(); ++i)
        c[i] += aux[i-diff];

    return c;
}
```

Edit Based on comment below objecting to use of [] vs iterators.

Personally I find iterators to be excessively verbose for something like this, but if you prefer them, then you could try somehting like the following:

```
std::vector<double> add(const std::vector<double>& a, 
                        const std::vector<double>& b)
{
    std::vector<double> c( (a.size() > b.size()) ? a : b);
    std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator c_i;

    const std::vector<double>& aux = (a.size() > b.size()) ? b : a;
    std::vector<double>::const_reverse_iterator aux_i;

    for (c_i=c.rbegin(), aux_i=aux.rbegin(); aux_i!=aux.rend(); ++c_i, ++aux_i)
        *c_i += *aux_i;

    return c;
}
```

I didn't test or compile either of these, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: additionally, if this operation makes sense for your particular domain and you use it everywhere, overload operator+ and do what andand says inside of the definition.

Comment: This does not reverse the order of the inputs.  Also dislike use of [] instead of iterators.

Comment: @Steve Townsend:  The OP didn't want to reverse the order of the inputs.  As for [] vs iterators, I grew up on Fortran, Pascal and C and find iterators to be excessively verbose for simple things like this... but I've updated for those interested in such things.

Comment: OP's question stated "I would like to add both vectors starting at the last element and working backwards".  Use of iterators may be verbose but it's more efficient and expressive than [].  We get pointer addition (or subtraction, since we are moving back) rather than multiplication to access via index.